# View not resizing on 3.5 inch screen

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have a main menu screen with a tab bar at the bottom. It's got a Pin > Bottom Space to Superview constraint. However, the main menu view does not resize when run on a 3.5 inch screen. The only way I can get the tab bar to show up is to run...

```
self.view.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
```

But when I do this, the tab bar stops responding. So I have two issues: 1) Why doesn't the constraint cause the view to resize properly?, and 2) Why does the tab bar stop responding when it's moved?

Comment: Do you have some code or image of what your referring too? If using auto layout in IB then pin the toolbar to the bottom of the screen and pin the view to the top and also the vertical spacing to the toolbar, this will allow the free movement. also make sure no height attribute is associated with the view.

Comment: Ah, I was constraining improperly. This was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It's important for you use constraints? You can simply use normal resize from the inspector:
[image]